# Session not correct after coming back from a third party site

Tags: php, session

Everything is working fine if all the processing happens on my own site. The session variable get stored and retrieved successfully.

Now I got a third part integration, which is processed via POST data. I have got `session_start()` called at the first line of each php file.

- **start_process.php** - sets some session variables as follows and calls third party that redirects to response.php

  ```
   $_SESSION["id"] = $id       // Echoing these shows the correct values 
   $_SESSION["name"]= $name    // Echoing these shows the correct values
  ```
- **response.php** - This page receives the response from the third party and tries to get the data from session variables

  ```
   $id = $_SESSION["id"]           // This comes out to be blank
   $name = $_SESSION["name"]       // This comes out to be blank
  ```

On my processing page i.e. the response.php, I am trying to retreive back the session values, I don't get the session variables back.

Searching on SO, few post suggest that to check the value of

```
echo session_id();
```

which comes to be as different on the first page and the later page coming back to my site. Searching further shows that the value of the following needs to be blank

```
echo ini_get('session.cookie_domain');
```

This indeed is blank. Now I am stuck as I see this value as blank, and even though the session is not getting loaded properly.

Can you please suggest what to do next? Any debugging? Any hints to solve this problem?

---

### Update

#### start_process.php

has a form whose post action is the url to third party site... as

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION["Check"] = "Abc";
echo session_id();
>
<form name="myform" action="http://<ThirdPartyUrl.com>/pathToSomePage.jsp" method="POST">
          <!-- some  hidden fields with value  and some other text fields -->
</form>
```

#### respone.php

The third party gives a response in post request again to my response page where I directly test the output of the POST variables and here I am trying to use my session variables

```
<?php session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION["Check"];
echo session_id(); // This is different from the one printed in the start_process.php page
?>
```

I don't think the third party hosting is on the same server, because currently I am on a shared host and the third party definitely has it's own server.

Comment: show some code please.

Comment: Try using [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Please explain why you feel this post should be closed? I am stuck here since long time and trying to get the solution or atleast the way to go forward..

Comment: Is the third party 'post' data being sent back to your website via a regular HTML Form, or is the data posted directly from their server? (e.g. JSP creating a POST request server-side)

Comment: @thaJeztah asked really important question... can you answer it? How POST request is made? Is it HTTP 3xx code with change of location (as in this case it should work just fine)? Can you provide more details about third party site, or their API at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've dealt with a similar problem when working on shopping cart payment gateway integrations. If the response script is ultimately contacted via the browser (i.e. the user is redirected to response.php after they're done on the 3rd party site), the session IDs and cookies will be preserved. If your response script is contacted via a server side request from the 3rd party site, that request is treated as an entirely new session. In that case a lot of integrations allow you to senda  "passthrough" variable that will be sent back to your response script along with the rest of the data generated by the 3rd party site. You can use this variable to connect the user's session to the server side request you receive later on (for example you could create a database that relates the two values). Alternatively you could "cheat" the system. If you're passing the response script location along with your request every time, you could build your own passthrough variable into it. So instead of something like

`<responseURL>www.mysite.com/response.php</responseURL>`

you could send

`<responseURL>www.mysite.com/response.php?key=abcd1234</responseURL>`

I would recommend setting the key parameter to the session ID directly, so you'd have to build something simple that could translate between the two (like the table I mentioned above).

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to know without seeing some more code (how start_process.php is hooking into the third-party code, how the third-party is coming back to response.php). Here are a couple guesses:

**Theory 1: third-party code is messing with your session (if hosted on the same server)**

Is this third-party integration hosted on your same server? If so, I would suspect that the third-party could be ending/recreating, or otherwise modifying your session.

**Theory 2: third-party is redirecting back to your site using a separate domain**

Is it possible that you start off at *mydomain.com* and the third-party redirects back to *www.mydomain.com* (or something like that)? Even though those two domains look like they should be the same, they are utterly different as far as PHP sessions are concerned, you'll end up with a different session.

Comment: Ok. Any word on Theory 2? I was helping someone else with a session ID issue nearly identical to your own. They realized that users would sometimes start out at _mydomain.com_ and the third-party site was redirecting back to _www.mydomain.com_ which created a new session.

Comment: I have rechecked the url. The request starts at and response comes at   *mydomain.com* and not to the *www* sub-domain.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to start a session before to use it. Before assign any value to a session valiable type into your code: session_start(); Do not forget to destroy/unset the session eighter. Hope it will work

Comment: Author of a question wrote: "I have got session_start() called at the first line of each php file."

Comment: you don't destroy a session. Also destroy and unset is different

Answer (score 1):

Use cookies with some specified expire timings ! it will works well. updated your question with some code so coder can debug it !

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: find the cookie!

You can loose at domain or directory level. See [session_set_cookie_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) specs.

What about the 3rd part. Does response.php requested from the same browser or from another web app, so have it the same cookie? It seems to me that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem is required to analyze the process steps to determine the place of every execution

If the thirdparty application is calling itselft to the URL of the response and is not a redirection into the client the sessions are not the same.

Example:

- Client navigates to start_process.php and a session is created for client
- start_process.php calls the thirdParty
- Thirdparty app calls response.php and a session for thirdparty is created

Is important to check that the session ID is maintained by the client cookie and validated in the server. The client that starts the process and the thirdparty are diferent "clients" of the app with their own sessions.

---

Diagram example that shows you are probably doing based on your question.

[image]

Probably you can't call the third party directly from the client. On the client call a page on your host that calls the third party and capture the response (for example using curl)

Diagram example:

[image]